# How to copy contents of one buffer pointer to another

Tags: c++, c, com, atl

I have the following pointer:

```
BSTR *PREVIOUS;
```

And I want make a new copy to:

```
BSTR *NEW;
```

I want to copy the CONTENTS/DATA (that PREVIOUS is pointing) from PREVIOUS to NEW.

I've just tried the following command, but it doesn't work:

```
memcpy(NEW,PREVIOUS,SysStringByteLen(*PREVIOUS));
```

I dont see any error when compiling because I am working on ATL COM environment. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you post some code to demonstrate the problem please?

Comment: I want to just make another copy of the contents that one buffer pointer is pointing to.

Comment: I am guessing with memcpy , I may be copying the addresses of the the data content but not sure about it

Comment: I have not allocated memory to New, I will try doing this .Thank you

Comment: I tried this *NEW = (BSTR)malloc(PREVIOUS);

memcpy(NEW,PREVIOUS,SysStringByteLen(*PREVIOUS)); but it did not work

Comment: As Adam pointed out in his answer BSTR is already a pointer. For more information on BSTR and why you should never use malloc, new, free, delete with it see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx Basically it has a different layout in memory than one would expect.

Comment: You should really include a complete block of code. You can either use `memcpy` or `strdup`, depending on the data type.

Comment: @Dogbert You cannot use the standard string functions with a BSTR. It has a differently memory layout than a normal C string. See the link I provided above.

Comment: I understand that much. That's why I noted `depending on the data type`. In pure C, memcpy should always work for buffers/blocks, with the exception of structures which contain pointer members, which would result in a mixed deep/shallow copy operation. :)

Comment: @Dogbert The data type is known here, so why suggest something that will not work for it? Neither memcpy or strdup will work as expected on a BSTR in most cases.

Comment: That sounds reasonable enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`BSTR` is itself already a pointer, you should almost always use just a plain `BSTR`, not a `BSTR*` (which is a pointer to a `BSTR`).  Ordinarily, you would copy a `BSTR` with [`SysAllocString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms891285.aspx):

```
BSTR NEW = SysAllocString(PREVIOUS);
```

If you really do have a pointer to a `BSTR` (such as via a function's out parameter), then you add a layer of indirection:

```
BSTR *PREVIOUS = ...;  // This must point to a valid BSTR
BSTR *NEW = ...;  // This must also point to a valid BSTR
*NEW = SysAllocString(*PREVIOUS);
```

Comment: I don't think NEW has to initially point to a valid BSTR if you are immediately assigning to it? But you would have to take the address of the BSTR coming back from SysAllocString, correct?

Comment: only *Previous is pointing to a BSTR and *NEW is the one which I want to copy the contents that Previous is pointing to